# How to implement Layout Manager with fixed layout size for multiple pictures?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing application where user can create notes. Note contains title, pictures and text. Note has few pictures, but also it can contains one picture or empty space. User adds pictures one by one. Pictures has layout container with fixed `200dp`. I should add unknown count of pictures into this container, where it will be beautifully composed like in picture below. How can I implement this?

Note creation Activity
[image]

I need to implement something like here

[image: layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use [Flexbox](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) by Google.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use GridLayoutManager check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) is to clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Recyclerview with staggeredLayout Manager.
`StaggeredGridLayoutManager` is similar with `GridLayoutManager` but in this each grid have its own size(width and height). It automatically sets the items according to their height and width. The main difference between GridView and Staggered Grid is of varying size in staggered. Staggered Grid View shows asymmetric items in view.

[image]

Pinterest is a example of staggered grid.
Check [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview) for more.

Answer (score 1):

try this you can use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` for this purpose

> because **StaggeredGridLayoutManager** is similar with **GridLayoutManager** but in this each grid have its own size(width and height). It automatically sets the items according to their height and width

```
private StaggeredGridLayoutManager gaggeredGridLayoutManager;
gaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gaggeredGridLayoutManager);
```

check this example of [StaggeredGridLayoutManager demo](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

[image]